# Wordpress Hide Add to Cart Multiple Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove/hide the add to cart button for around 8 categories. What needs to happen is every product in the 8 categories needs to have the add to cart button hidden/removed.

I have this code already however only works for one category:

`function themepaint_custom_cart_buttons(){
   $product = get_product();
   if ( has_term( 'cases', 'product_cat') ){
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
   }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'themepaint_custom_cart_buttons' );`

Comment: Is it 30 - your category id for which you've already removed buttons?

Comment: No, Code above removes add to cart button from products within the category slug of: cases

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used an array with has_term.

For future reference:

> if ( has_term( array( 'coolers', 'cases', 'ram', 'storage' ), 'product_cat') ){